# Character encoding of PHP files, only Notepad++ works?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, character, notepad++

I'm uploading changes to a remote server. PHP web pages are configured with the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

... and **I cannot change it** to UTF-8 (it would solve my problems).

#### With Notepadd++

When I edit my file with i.e. notepad++ all works fine.I can correctly see accented characters like "é à ò". I correctly upload changes to the server.

#### With my IDE (the problem)

When I use my favourite IDE (PHPStorm) accented characters are displayed as � (in the IDE itself). If I made some changes and upload the file to the server, accented characters are replaced with ï¿½.

I've to admin I'm not really an expert in file encodings. I just need a way to understand why Notepad++ is working while PHPStorm isn't.

Comment: Open the "Encoding" menu on N++ -- what do you see?

Comment: @Jon I can see ANSI... but I cannot understand why it's not working in PHPStorm!

Comment: You can also see "Convert to UTF-8"...

Comment: PHPStorm tries to detect file encoding, and what it can not it falls back to the [project setting](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/encoding.html) (settings => project => file encodings). Your files' encoding cannot be detected and PHPStorm is probably configured for UTF-8, so it can't read them. Convert the files to UTF-8.

Comment: @gremo yeah you should! Ascii is so 1998. UTF-8 gives you way more characters that you don't have to care about anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help if you change the file encoding to ISO-8859-1 in PHPStorm settings?

Project Settings > File Encodings (http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html)

As you've already said, the correct thing to do is to get *everything* to be UTF-8, but as you can't do that, changing your PHPStorm IDE to default to ISO-8859-1 might get around the issue for now.